# How to find coefficient of $f(z)$, if $f(z)$ is differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z=x+iy$, $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. $f(z)=6x-4y+i(ax+by)$, $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. If $f(z)$ is differentiable, find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Cauchy Riemann Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)?

Comment: You need to check if $f(z+h)-f(z)=w\cdot h+o(h)$. Calculate and simplify the left hand side with $z=x+iy$ and $h=u+iv$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a complex fuction $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ is differentiable, it's real and imaginary parts should satisfy Cauchy-Riemann condition: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ and  $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
so in your case $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 6$,$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = b$,
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -4$ ,$-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = a$. It gives:
$$a =4,b=6$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable as a *complex* function, it must fulfill $$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{\partial \Re(f(x+iy))}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial \Im(f(x+iy))}{\partial y} \\
  \frac{\partial \Re(f(x+iy))}{\partial y} &=& -\frac{\partial \Im(f(x+iy))}{\partial x}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
where $\Re(z)$ denotes the real part and $\Im(z)$ the imaginary part of a $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Those equations are called the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations.

If you compute these derivatives, you should be able to determine which values $a$ and $b$ must take to have your $f$ fulfill these equations.